# Not able to read the json body response from aws lambda (java). It says ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a serverless system, where my backend is in AWS lambda(java) and frontend is in react. 
I am sending a user entered name value and expect a hello {name} in return.
I use fetch api (post) to send user entered data in this case "name" to the backend lambda. The lambda is able to print it and modify it. It sends the jsonnode response back to the frontend, but on the frontend when i console.log(response) it does not print anything in the body.

It says body:{...} and on clicking on the three dots it says Object ReadableStream. 
body: ReadableStream
locked: false

I do see the updated value in the -> Network->Response.(when troubleshooting via chrome dev tools). How can I access this value and use it on the front end?

Backend Code:

```
public class DataProcessor {

    LambdaLogger logger;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public void handler(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {

        this.logger = context.getLogger();
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        logger.log("Beginning data processing");

        // Get our inputs
        JsonNode body = this.extractBody(inputStream);

        logger.log(body.toString());

        String username = body.get("headers").get("X-FORWARDED-USER").toString().replace("\"", "");
        String method = body.get("httpMethod").toString().replace("\"", "");
        String path = body.get("path").toString().replace("\"", "");
        String data = body.get("body").toString().replace("\"", "");
        Boolean isBase64Encoded = body.get("isBase64Encoded").asBoolean();

        if (isBase64Encoded) {
          data = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data), "utf-8");
        }

        logger.log("username: " + username);
        logger.log("method: " + method);
        logger.log("path: " + path);
        logger.log("data: " + data);
        logger.log("isBase64Encoded: " + isBase64Encoded);

        JsonNode responseJson;

        responseJson =  (JsonNode)constructResponse(data);

        logger.log("Response: " + responseJson.toString());

        // Output the response
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(responseJson.toString());
        writer.close();
    }

    // construct response
    private ObjectNode constructResponse(String body) throws IOException {
      ObjectNode response = this.objectMapper.createObjectNode();
      response.put("statusCode", 200);
      response.put("isBase64Encoded", true);
      response.put("body", body);
      response.put("headers", this.objectMapper.readTree("{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"}"));
      return response;
    }

    // get body from inputStream
    private JsonNode extractBody(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode input = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, JsonNode.class);
        return input;
    }
}
```

Frontend UI code

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={ name: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = event =>{
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]:event.target.value })
  }

  handleClick = event =>{
    this.setState(state => ({
        isFormOn: !state.isFormOn,
        name: state.name
    }));
  }

  handleSubmit = event =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Name : " + this.state.name)

    const url ="abc"

    const data = { name:this.state.name}

    console.log("Data is : ", data)

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
     })
     .then(function(response){
        console.log("Response is : ", response);
        let json = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log("This is json parsed string : ", JSON.stringify(json));
     })
     .then(data => console.log("data is : ", data))
     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    Name : <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            }
        </div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Try `response.text()` ? Also see [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) on mdn. Especially [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text). You may also want to use [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or an [ajax library](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you need cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. response.text() worked. I do have to JSON.parse(body) after response.text() to get the individual fields though. But this worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read and parse the response using [json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), which takes a Response stream and reads it to completion:

```
 fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
 })
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => console.log("data is : ", data))
 .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
```

Comment: I get this error if I do the above : Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0